# Inner classes vs. immutability in Scala

Tags: scala, immutability, inner-classes

Please look at the following toy example:

```
case class Person(name: String, address: Person#Address = null) {
  case class Address(street: String, city: String, state: String) {
    def prettyFormat = s"To $name of $city" // note I use name here
  }

  def setAddress(street: String, city: String, state: String): Person =
    copy(address=Address(street,city,state))

  def setName(n: String): Person = copy(name=n)
}
```

Do you see a bug there? Yes, the following code will print the same message (John) in both cases:

```
val p1 = Person("John").setAddress("Main", "Johntown", "NY")
println(p1.address.prettyFormat) // prints To John of Johntown
val p2 = p1.setName("Jane")
println(p2.address.prettyFormat) // prints To John of Johntown
```

Naturally this is because of the $outer reference in Address that is preserved in set methods, so the p2 inner object still refers to John. The issue could be fixed by the following or by recreation of the Address object (wouldn't it be nice if we had precooked copy-constructors in case classes?):

```
def setName(n: String) = copy(name=n).setAddress(address.street,address.city,address.state)
```

However, the problem becomes more annoying where there are several inner objects like this and tens of methods like setName. So my conclusion is that **immutability and class-inner classes are mutually incompatible**.

*Question: is there a design pattern or a useful idiom for a structure of nested immutable objects in which inner objects need access to the outer objects to do their job.*

So far I have considered passing person as implicit to prettyFormat or wrapping the inner methods into a Reader monad, so the current person will be applied to the monad returned by prettyFormat. Any other great ideas?

Comment: Given that both inner and outer classes are immutable, what exactly is the problem? If you update John's address, you will be constructing a new address instance to be held in the updated/copied person instance for John. This won't have any effect on Jane's address (and vice-versa if you update Jane's address).

Comment: The problem is well represented by the test I've put there: changing p1 name to Jane just doesn't work, the second print prints John!

Comment: No, it prints Jane's address, which, by construction, happens to be the same as John's address. If you don't want Jane having the same address, call setAddress on the result of `p1.setName`.

Comment: It prints John's name after I set it to "Jane" - this is my problem.

Comment: Ah, I see - your `prettyFormat` definition inside `Address` is referencing a variable defined outside of it - yes, doing that will cause issues. I would suggest moving that method up into the `Person` class.

Comment: @Shadowlands You are getting closer, now replace the toy problem with a very complex algorithm and multi-level data that needs to be maintained by it. I am trying to break-up the algorithm and encapsulate parts of it in the corresponding inner objects rather than implementing the whole mess in one class.

Comment: Why are you trying so hard to keep the case classes nested?  Personally I would avoid nesting the case classes which bypasses the problem.

Comment: @Chris K Think about a complex data structure instead of the toy problem, pushing all fields (tens of them) into one case class will be unmanageable (not even to mention basic encapsulation principles).

Comment: @JacobEckel I did not mean to suggest flattening the fields, what I was getting at was to not nest the case classes.  eg Address still exists, it is just at the same level as Person.

Comment: Even if they are on the same level I see no robust way to reach for Person's name from Address.prettyFormat code. Assuming immutability semantics this will not work for the same reasons: $outer.person.name

Comment: @JacobEckel precisely, there is not.  Scala aside, you have an object modelling problem.  What is your view of circular references within a domain model?   Nesting the case classes has created a circular reference implicitly, moving the nested case classes out makes that circular reference explicit and more importantly obvious to all.  Whether that is a good idea or not depends on your view of whether allowing circular references in the first place is good or not, but that aside I suggest that making it explicit helps to make this behaviour obvious to all (and thus helps to avoid some bugs).

Answer (score 6):

It is not that immutability and class-inner classes are mutually incompatible, but when you create your inner address class, it is bind to that Person instance (else you would use a static inner class, i.e., define Address in a companion object).

You problem is more with the semantics of the `copy` method provided for case classes, which does not consider inner classes. So either you drop immutability or you create a REAL new Person on modification:

```
def setName(n: String): Person = Person(n, street, city, state)
```

Do note that I should not pass a direct `Address` instance to `Person()`, your very definition is that each Address type is part of a single person and only makes sense for that person, so it can't exist outside of that person, and I can't pass it from the outside to a new person being created. Again, if this is not the case, then you need to rethink you structure with different semantics.

Personally, I thing the following is much clearer/intuitive as a description of the domain:

```
case class Address(street: String, city: String, state: String)
case class Person(name: String, address: Address) {
   def prettyFormat = s"To $name of ${address.city}"
}
```

And then you can create copies of addresses/people with little worry and full immutability.

Comment: Indeed one of the solutions may be to override copy to make it deep-copy and "inner-object" recreative. That is why I wished for precooked copy-constructors for case classes.  As to your second suggestion, firstly, pretty-printing of addresses doesn't belong in the Person class and secondly, following this logic I will have to push all methods of a complex system into the outer class, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm not convinced. it is more than "pretty-printing of addresses". It is the address for THAT person and includes the name of THAT person. It seems mush more intuitive to me to think that "a person has an address" than "an address has a person" (or the 2-sided relationship you are attempting). I'm not proposing you move ALL methods of a complex system into a single class. Some might make more sense in the inner (say, if you just print street, city and state), some might make more sense outside of those objects and as helper functions receiving parameters. But something needs to change...

Answer (score 3):

Use lenses to access nested immutable objects.

The boilerplate addressed by lenses already sets in with `setAddress`.

```
scala> case class Parent(name: String, child: Parent#Child) { case class Child(name: String) { def parent = Parent.this.name } }
defined class Parent
```

A would-be parent.

```
scala> val p1 = Parent("Bob", null)
p1: Parent = Parent(Bob,null)

scala> val p2 = Parent("Bob", new p1.Child("Billy"))
p2: Parent = Parent(Bob,Child(Billy))
```

Bob undergoes a change, but the child doesn't know her name.

```
scala> val p3 = p2.copy(name = "Mary")
p3: Parent = Parent(Mary,Child(Billy))

scala> p3.child.parent
res0: String = Bob

scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> val parentName = Lens.lensu[Parent,String]((a,v)=>a.copy(name=v),_.name)
parentName: scalaz.Lens[Parent,String] = scalaz.LensFunctions$$anon$5@39bd45b4
```

Sample name transform.

```
scala> parentName =>= (_ + " Jo")
res1: Parent => Parent = <function1>

scala> res1(p1)
res3: Parent = Parent(Bob Jo,null)

scala> val parentChild = Lens.lensu[Parent, Parent#Child]((a,v)=>a.copy(child=a.Child(v.name)), _.child)
parentChild: scalaz.Lens[Parent,Parent#Child] = scalaz.LensFunctions$$anon$5@3cdeef1e

scala> val adopt = parentChild =>= identity
adopt: Parent => Parent = <function1>
```

If the parent name changes, the child must adopt it.

```
scala> val rename = res1 andThen adopt
rename: Parent => Parent = <function1>

scala> val p4 = rename(p3)
p4: Parent = Parent(Mary Jo,Child(Billy))

scala> p4.child.parent
res4: String = Mary Jo
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question: is there a design pattern or a useful idiom for a structure of nested immutable objects in which inner objects need access to the outer objects to do their job.

I don't think so, no.

The "outer" object will necessarily have a reference to the "inner" object.

By using nested classes, you have created a (hidden) reference to the "outer" object from the "inner" one. This confuses the "case class" machinery in Scala, as you have seen in your example.

Therefore, your two classes are 1-1 and mutually interdependent by design. It would be simpler and clearer to have them both in a single class, if they are really 1-1.